# functions aren't fired at once as expected on click event, need to click twice to see all changes

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I have a script with a slider (bxslider). For every part of the slide show (slides that share the same id) there are different clip thumbnails below the current slide.

There are also some buttons (previous slide, next slide, go to another slide part). After clicking one of them following function (just one of them) is fired:

```
$('#bx-pager a').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var pagelink = $(this).attr('data-slide-index');
            start_count = pagelink;

            if (start_count > 0) {
                console.log('bxpagerv click display before');
                $('#slider-prev').css('display', 'inline');
                console.log('bxpagerv click display after');
            }
            if (start_count == 0) {
                console.log('bxpagerv click display not before');
                $('#slider-prev').css('display', 'none');
                console.log('bxpagerv click display not after');
            }
            ...//here is some other code to show or hide navigational elements
            mark_active_pdf(start_count);
            pagination();
});
```

At the end these two functions are called: 
This one to underline the active slide part (there is a navigation over the slider where you can skip to the next or previous part (list elements with the same class)):

```
function mark_active_pdf(start_count) {
        var current_slide_clid = $('.bxslider li').eq(start_count).attr('class');
        $('#bx-pager a#' + current_slide_clid).css({ "text-decoration": "underline" });
        $('#bx-pager a').not('#' + current_slide_clid).css({ "text-decoration": "none" });
        ...
}
```

This function hides clip thumbnails if there are more than four.

```
function pagination() {
        var cur_sli;
        if (typeof current_slide() != "undefined") {
            cur_sli = current_slide();
        }
        else {
            cur_sli = $('.bxslider li').eq(0).attr('class');
        }
        console.log(cur_sli);
        var thumb_count = $('#clips ul li.' + cur_sli).length;
        console.log('thumb_count: ' + thumb_count);
        if (thumb_count > 4) {
            for (var l = 4; l < thumb_count; l++) {
                $('#clips ul li.' + cur_sli + ':eq(' + l + ')').addClass("invisible");
                $('#clips ul li.invisible').css({ "display": "none" });
            }
            $('#clip_control_right').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#clip_control_right').hide();
            $('#clip_control_left').hide();
        }

}
```

The pagination function also uses this function to get the id of the currently displayed slide part pdf:

```
function current_slide() {       
        var current_slide_id;
        $('.bxslider').find('li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('z-index') == 50) {
                current_slide_id = $(this).prop('class');
            }
        });        
        return current_slide_id;
    }
```

However - With the first click on the navigation element only the new active element gets underlined. But to hide the clip thumbnails I have to click another time. But why?

Comment: console.log `pagelink`, something tells me it's undefined the first time. Why exactly did you think it was a good idea to set a local variable to a global variable (`start_count`) when you pass it along anyway as an argument ?

Comment: sorry, pagelink is not in the code. The whole script is way too long to post it here. But before adding my pagination function everything worked fine so I guess whatever the error is causing is in these code snippets. About the start_count variable - I don't know anymore why. Maybe keeping it global caused errors ...

Comment: What do you mean `pagelink` is not in the code, it's where you get the initial value of the data attribute ?

Comment: No it's in the code. even in the posted snippets above. It's a variable that gets a value from the html code.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The problem was that my `current_slide()` function returned the current slide's id but the id of the target (the slide the link skips to) was needed. So my function was one step behind and I had to click twice.